# How to integrate greatest integer and fractional part

Tags: integration, step-function

Integrate this function: $⌊x^2⌋ + \{x^2\}$ , from $0$ to $2$

I know that the first part is a step function, and every integer value, say, from 1 to 2, will be 1. But I can't understand how to integrate it. Also does the square matter if its outside the bracket or inside?

Comment: Are you asking if $\lfloor x^2\rfloor=\lfloor x\rfloor^2$?  or if $\{x^2\}=\{x\}^2$Try values, like $\sqrt 2$ (works for both).

Comment: Hint for the integral:  break it regions of continuity.

Comment: I have edited the question. It is the former. Do we have to do this by use of a diagram?

Comment: I don't see how a diagram is relevant.  The two terms have jump discontinuities whenever $x^2$ passes over an integer.  As $x$ is running from $0$ to $2$ we see that $x^2$ is running from $0$ to $4$ so you just need to break the region up as $[0,1],[1,\sqrt 2],[\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3],[\sqrt 3,2]$.

Comment: On second thought, I am overcomplicating matters.  For any $z$ we have $\lfloor z \rfloor +\{z\}=z$.

Answer (score 1):

As Iulu stated in the comments, it does matter whether the square is on the outside or the inside, but as you've written the problem here, since $\lfloor z \rfloor +\{z\}=z$, we have $\lfloor x^2 \rfloor +\{x^2\}=x^2$. And thus we have
$$\int_0^2 \lfloor x^2 \rfloor +\{x^2\} \ dx = \int_0^2 x^2=\frac{x^3}{3}\bigg|_0^2 = \frac{8}{3}$$

What may be slightly more interesting, however, would be an evaluation of the two parts individually. For
$$\int_0^2 \lfloor x^2 \rfloor \ dx$$
we can split the integral into parts as follows. For $0<x<1$, we have $\lfloor x^2 \rfloor = 0$. For $1<x<\sqrt{2}$, we have $\lfloor x^2 \rfloor=1$, and in general we have for $\sqrt{n}<x<\sqrt{n+1}$, we have $\lfloor x^2 \rfloor =n$. So splitting up the integral we get
$$\int_0^2 \lfloor x^2 \rfloor \ dx = \sum_{n=0}^3 \int_{\sqrt{n}}^{\sqrt{n+1}} n 
 \ dx = \sum_{n=1}^{3}n(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})=3\sqrt{4}-\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{1}=5-\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}$$
Note that we can do  a similar splitting of the integral for the fractional part, but I'll leave that as an optional excercise.

Comment: Thank you. Why would the answer change if the square was outside?

Comment: @user585380 Basically because in general $\lfloor x^2 \rfloor \neq \lfloor x \rfloor^2$. Try $x=1.5$ for example. I can do the other integral if you want, but I bet you could do it as well if you use the same splitting into a sum strategy which I used.

Comment: I tried for x = 1.5. So I have to take the limits from 0 to 1 and 1 to 2. I got the answer as simply 1. I think this might be wrong. Could you steer me in the right direction?

Comment: I'm sorry, what did you integrate? Are you putting the squares on the outside now? Also, trying $x=1.5$ was just mean to show that $\lfloor x^2 \rfloor \neq \lfloor x \rfloor^2$, since $2 \neq 1 \implies \lfloor 2.25 \rfloor \neq \lfloor 1.5 \rfloor^2$.

Comment: If you are trying to integrate the fractional part now, note that you have to split it up into intervals from $0$ to $1$, $1$ to $\sqrt{2}$, $\sqrt{2}$ to $\sqrt{3}$, and $\sqrt{3}$ to $2$. Do you see why?